# how to refresh values while redirecting to other page in angular factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have an multipage application in which i am using angular js, i have my angular controller which is simple and uses the logic which is placed under my angular factory js.

The example i have is that on the first page i have inputs which caters my search parameters on click of search button the results are shown on my second page, first time it works fine.
Now i navigate back to my first search page via browser back button and modify the search parameters on click of search button now i am not able to view the search results or rather the new parameters which i have passed are not getting refreshed.

In short when i am redirecting using angular js, the parameters in the angular factory are not set or rather the values are not refreshed after the second redirect.
How can i refresh the values every time i redirect to some other page using angular factory.

Comment: Would help if you showed some code :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved.
used factory for sharing the values between controllers and services for getting values from server side.

the issue i had is that i had not created my factory properly.